# Using room twice

Tags: redundancy, attributive-nouns

I have a game where an external character can use a room. There is a room known as “War Room”. When the character used the room, like any other, a log will be produced that states “Fred has used the War Room room.”

Is this correct since War Room is a name and room is the type?

Comment: War Room room would normally be wrong, though understood. Be aware of regional differences, for instance in some English-speaking countries a house will have a laundry room, while in others the room is just called a laundry.

Comment: Can't you write your room-logging code to only append the word "room" when it's not already in the room's name? Do you have any other rooms where adding "room" makes it weird? (For example,, I think "...has used the kitchen room",  "bedroom room" and "armory room" all sound wrong.)

Comment: Someone has gone and painted you into a corner. Who said you have to state War Room room, when we already know it's a room? Menus don't offer Tossed Salad salad or Apple Pie dessert.

Comment: Thanks for your help! There is no painting going, it’s just this is the only room with room in it’s name, and it got me thinking whether it would be correct in this instance since a room is an entity that the player can install. But it seems the correct way is to remove the redundant room based on the comments so far.

Comment: It seems a little odd to me that none of the other rooms has "room" in its name and that you would, in the absence of that, want to add "room" to those names in the log. As @nnnnnn says references to " the kitchen room", "the laboratory room", "the library room" and so on are vanishingly rare. Could you give examples of names of other rooms in the game  please?

Comment: Thinking about it, since it is a log and normal grammar rules do not necessarily apply, you could use the form "Fred has used room 'War Room'" "Fred has used room 'Laboratory'" and so on. It still uses "room" twice in the case of the War Room but demonstrates clearly that 'War Room' is the name of the room. If you add another room with "room" in the name it will still work. For instance "Fred has used room 'Interrogation Room' would be fine.